# OpenShift namespace creation (OCP) with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, openshift, azure-aks

I have the doubt if it is possible to create namespaces in openshift (OCP) using terraform templates, if possible what options would I have to create the namespace in different clusters as there are both development and production, with options I mean what forms of authentication would be?

At least for the namespace in AKS if I have a guide, since they use the credentials of the .kube/config file to authenticate but in OCP I do not know if it is similar.

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path    = "./.kube/config"
  config_context = var.context
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = var.name
    labels = var.labels
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_pod" "example_pod" {
  count = var.num_micros

  metadata {
    name      = "${var.name}-${count.index + 1}"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.example.metadata[0].name
  }

  spec {
    container {
      name  = "mycontainer"
      image = "nginx:latest"
    }
  }
}
```

If someone has a template of what I wrote at the beginning I would be grateful if you could share it with me or tell me about some documentation that would allow me to achieve my goal.